# Effectively Design a Simple Mail Client

Tags: database, architecture, data-structures, storage, email-client

`Requirement : JAVA desktop mail client which could connect to existing gmail,y! mail a/c & will allow receive/send mails, support offline view of mails, plus with more features as & when it comes. i am using Java Mail Api's`

`Underlying Mail Storage:  I have decided to use HSQLDB with 
Hibernate. Email content can have attachments , HTML , so i decided to use LONGVARBINARY type to store the email Body & attachments.`

> `Please let me know whether this approach is good & will it give me good performance when it comes to retrieval. Also give me some pointers on how to store java email objects in HSQLDB into LONGVARBINARY type & how to dereference it to get the actual data. ??`

<strike>2)I am confused over this because , with Approach 1 , i will end up storing all mail contents somehow on my local disk to enable offline viewing. And imagine if i have 1GB of mails ></strike>

Answer (score 1):

If you use a file-based approach (and this doesn't exclude you from using a database), you could compress and decompress the file(s) you use for persistence when not in use. Since you will be storing simple text, the compression is likely to be significant and the speed decrease would not be all that bad if you do it at intelligently chosen times. Hell, you could even make it an option.

The biggest thing (for me) to consider here is search time. What will you want the users to be able to search? If searching is important, I would probably use a database. My initial approach to the problem would be to store the subject and header information (dates, sender, recipient, etc) in separate columns, and then serialize the entire email object into a binary data column (possibly compressed). This would make full-text searches take longer, but that's to be expected anyway, right?

Comment: Good one Josh. Technically can you tell me how i can store email object in DB . Any specific technology that i need to use & also will simple select queries search & select the serialised binary data column to get me the correct record or is there something more one should do.

Comment: I am not worried about full text searches.